# How to get complex types in WSDL files with Java?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, castor, complextype

I have read similar topics and examples, but I have still some problems about getting WSDL schema content with complex types from WSDLs.

I am using WSDL4J, Castor and JDOM libraries.

```
            org.exolab.castor.xml.schema.Schema castorSchema = null ;
            if(theWSDL.getTypes() !=null &&  theWSDL.getTypes().getExtensibilityElements() !=null){
                for (Object e : theWSDL.getTypes().getExtensibilityElements()) {
                    schema = (Schema)e;
                }
            }

            if (schema != null) {
                DOMBuilder domBuilder = new DOMBuilder();
                Element jdomSchemaElement = domBuilder.build(schema.getElement());
                XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
                String xmlout = outputter.outputString(jdomSchemaElement.getDocument());

                StringReader in2 = new StringReader(xmlout);
                InputSource schemaSource = new InputSource(in2);

                SchemaReader schemaReader;
                try {
                    schemaReader = new SchemaReader(schemaSource);
                    castorSchema= schemaReader.read();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

This code works for some WSDL files but for some WSDL files, I am getting this error for line "castorSchema= schemaReader.read();":

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: getComplexType: Namespace prefix not recognized 'tns:cEstado'
>       at org.exolab.castor.xml.schema.Schema.getComplexType(Schema.java:951)
>       at org.exolab.castor.xml.schema.TypeReference.resolveTypeReference(TypeReference.java:122)
>       at org.exolab.castor.xml.schema.TypeReference.getType(TypeReference.java:71)
>       at org.exolab.castor.xml.schema.ElementDecl.getType(ElementDecl.java:349)
>       at org.exolab.castor.xml.schema.ElementDecl.validate(ElementDecl.java:809)
>       at org.exolab.castor.xml.schema.Group.validate(Group.java:463)
>       at org.exolab.castor.xml.schema.ComplexType.validate(ComplexType.java:815)
>       at org.exolab.castor.xml.schema.Schema.validate(Schema.java:2206)
>       at org.exolab.castor.xml.schema.reader.SchemaReader.read(SchemaReader.java:261)
>       at network.WSNetwork.execute(WSNetwork.java:105)
>       at network.WSNetwork.main(WSNetwork.java:61)

The wsdl file part about complex types in schema:

> 

```
    <s:complexType>

      <s:sequence>

        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="getestadosResult" type="tns:ArrayOfCEstado" />

      </s:sequence>

    </s:complexType>

  </s:element>

  <s:complexType name="ArrayOfCEstado">

    <s:sequence>

      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="cEstado" nillable="true" type="tns:cEstado" />

    </s:sequence>

  </s:complexType>

  <s:complexType name="cEstado">

    <s:sequence>

      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="IdEstado" type="s:string" />

      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Estado" type="s:string" />

      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Err" type="s:string" />

    </s:sequence>

  </s:complexType>
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Any specific reason why you can't use wsimport to create the ws artifacts or JAXB to create the Java to XML bindings?

Comment: In fact, no there is no specific reason. When I searched the net, i found these libraries and read that they are useful for wsdl operations, so I chose them. By the way, during debug, I saw that XMLOutputter did not add tns namespace to the schema, that is why I got the error.. But I did not understand why and dont know how to fix that..

Comment: Is that namespace duplicated within the schema?

Comment: No, it is added into the definitions tag for just once.

Comment: I added this line when I get the jdom element and it fixed my problem. jdomSchemaElement.addNamespaceDeclaration(Namespace.getNamespace("tns", ns.get("tns").toString()));

Comment: cool deal. Glad you figured it out and got it working.